# $ a $ and $b$ are real numbers with $0 < b < a$. Prove that if $n$ is a positive integer, then $a^n - b^n \leq na^{n-1}(a - b)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm taking a basic discrete math course and I'm having a hard time with Mathematical Induction.

The problem is stated as:

> Suppose that $ a $ and $b$ are real numbers with $0 < b < a$. Prove that if $n$ is a positive integer, then $a^n - b^n \leq na^{n-1}(a - b)$.

#### The work I have so far is:

- Basis Step:
  $$\begin{aligned} 
  P(1) \equiv a^1 - b^1 &\leq (1)a^{(0)}(a - b) \\\
  a - b &\leq (1)(1)(a - b) \\\
  a - b &\leq a - b
  \end{aligned}$$
- Inductive Step:
  Assume that $P(k)$ is true for any fixed integer $k \geq 0$. 
  *Induction Hypothesis*: $$ P(k) \equiv a^k-b^k \leq ka^{k-1}(a-b)$$
  Prove that $ P(k+1) $ is true given $P(k)$:
  $$\begin{aligned}
  P(k+1) &\equiv& a^{k+1} - b^{k+1} &\leq (k+1)a^k(a-b)\\\
  &\equiv& a\cdot a^k - b \cdot b^k &\leq (k+1)a^k(a-b)\\\
  &\equiv& a\cdot a^k - b \cdot b^k &\leq ka^k(a-b) + a^k(a-b)\\\
  &\equiv& a\cdot a^k - b \cdot b^k &\leq a \cdot \underbrace{\left( ka^{k-1}(a-b) \right)}_{IH} + a^k(a-b)\\\
  \end{aligned}$$

#### Where I'm At

I don't really know where to go from there.  I think I'm supposed to play around with the left side such that I can find the other part of my Induction Hypothesis on the left side, but I'm lost at that point.

Comment: I don't think $ 0 $ counts as a positive integer, so you should refactor your base case for $ n = 1 $.

Comment: True, I forgot about that somewhere in my transcription from paper to computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint (rather big, imo);

$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})\le (a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-1}+\ldots$$

Comment: For the right part of the inequation, how does $(a - b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-1} + \ldots$ go past the dots?

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Since $b<a$, then $0<a-b$, so $a^n-b^n\le na^{n-1}(a-b)$ if and only if $$\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}\le na^{n-1}.\tag{1}$$ We can write the left hand side of $(1)$ as $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^kb^{n-1-j}.\tag{2}$$ Use the fact that $0<b<a$ to get the rest of the way. There is no need for induction if you know that $(2)$ holds.