# Prove that $(x^{n} - y^{n} )/ (x - y)$ is larger than $ny^{n-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am doing the pratice in the Junior Problem Seminar by Dr. David A. SANTOS. I came across a question in chapter 2.4 that i had no idea how to do it. This is the question:

141. Let n be a positive integer and x > y. Prove that $(x^{n} - y^{n}) / (x-y) > ny^{n-1}$

Link of the book : https://www.rotupitti.it/materiali/Santos_Jiunior%20problem%20seminar_2008.pdf

So, $(x^{n} - y^{n}) / (x - y) = (x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + ... + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1}) $ but i am stuck here.

Comment: $x^{n-1}>y^{n-1}, x^{n-2}y>y^{n-2}y=y^{n-1} $ etc.

Comment: Parentheses, please.  $x^n-y^n/x-y=x^n-\frac {y^n}x-y$ and your conclusion does not follow.

Comment: You are all but done.  $x^{n-1-k}y^k > x^{n-1-k}y^k = x^{n-1}$.  So $(x^{n} - y^{n}) / (x - y) = (x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + ... + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1})> y^{n-1} + y^{n-1} + ...... + y^{n-1}$.

Comment: It seems like you'll need $x,y>0$ for this to be true, but maybe I'm wrong? $n=3, x=-1, y=-2$ gives $(x^n-y^n)/(x-y)=7,$ $ny^2=12.$

Comment: Oh.... wait.  Is $y >0$.  Don't think this is true if we allow $y < 0$.

Comment: So, without additional assumptions, like $y\geq 0,$ this is not true.

Comment: **Dupe* of: [$\, a $ and $b$ are real numbers with $0 &lt; b &lt; a$. Prove that if $n$ is a positive integer, then $a^n - b^n \leq na^{n-1}(a - b)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329983/a-and-b-are-real-numbers-with-0-b-a-prove-that-if-n-is-a-positive)

Comment: Also many other dupe targets, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1022226/242).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly used the books lesson that $\frac{x^{n} - y^{n}}{x - y} = x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + ... + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1}$

The tricks to solve the problem is to first realize there are $n$ summands in that sum.  Thus the sum will be at least $n\times \min{x^{n-k-1}y^k}$.

(I don't know if the book ever spelled this out but for any $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 +..... + a_n$ it should be pretty clear that:  For any summand $a_k$ we have, by definition, $\min (a_i) \le a_k \le \max (a_i)$ and that $n\times \min(a_i) \le a_1 + a_2 +....+a_n \le n\times \max(a_i)$ by induction)

And then to realize that if $0\le y < x$ then for each summand $x^{n-1-k}y^k$ we have $y^{n-1} < x^{n-1}y^k < x^{n-1}$ and so putting it all together:  $nx^{n-1} < \frac {x^n - y^2}{x-y} < nx^{n-1}$

(This is because if $a < b$ and $c > 0$ then $ac < bc$.  Thus if $0< y < x$ then $$y^{n-1} = y\cdot y^{n-2} < x\cdot y{n-2} = y\cdot xy^{n-3} < x\cdot xy^{n-3}=x^2y^{n-3} ........ x^{n-3}y^2= y\cdot x^{n-3}y < x\cdot x^{n-3}y = x^{n-2}y=yx^{n-2}<x\cdot x^{n-2}=x^{n-1}$$)

Unfortunately the book made an omission and forgot to specify that we must have $0 \le y$.

We assumed that $x^{n-k}y^k < x^{n-k+1}y^{k-1}$ because we assumed that $x^{n-k}y^k = y\times x^{n-k}y^{k-1} < x\times x^{n-k}y^{k-1}= x^{n-k+1}y^{k-1}$.

That is only true *if* we know that $x^{n-k}y^{k-1} > 0$.  If $x^{n-k}y^{k-1}=0$ then $x\times x^{n-k}y^{k-1}=0 =y\times x^{n-k}y^{k-1}$ and if $x^{n-k}y^{k-1} < 0$ we get the exact *opposite* result.  $x\times x^{n-k}y^{k-1} < y\times x^{n-k}y^{k-1}$.

And if we have $y < 0$ we can indeed have $x^{n-k}y^{k-1}< 0$ and we can come up with counter examples.

Answer (score 0):

ETA: As pointed out in the comments below, we need to take care that $x^n-y^n$, $x$, $y$ are *positive*, or equivalently, $x>y\ge 0$. Otherwise counterexamples include the instances $x=2,y=-10, n$ odd [so $n-1$ is even and $y^{n-1}$ is positive], $x=2,y=10$, $x=-2,y=10$.

HINT: The condition $x > y \ge 0$ gives $x^{n-i-1}y^i \ge y^{n-1}$ for each $i=0,1,\ldots,n-1$. Using this observation, what can you conclude about $$\frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y} = $$ $$x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + \ldots + xy^{n-2}$$ $$+ y^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Why assume WLOG $x> y$? That was a given.  And there sure *is* a lack of generality!  If $x \le y$ then the opposite result occurs!

Comment: Yeah, WLOG is entirely wrong here. You are also assuming $y\geq 0$ here, which is not stated in the question. If $x=1, y=-2,$ then $xy^2>x^3.$

Comment: Yes, both of you are right. I fixed my post accordingly